# How to disable automatic scroll to text input when typing?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying leave a bit of space under the input field when the soft keyboard is open so it does not overlap the submit button.

[image: The keyboard should not overlap the submit button]

The lib I'm using to achieve this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

windowSoftInputMode is set to "adjustPan".

It works flawlesly on iOS. On Android the scroll offset gets reset as soon as the user starts typing.

Rough app structure:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingScrollView
  enableOnAndroid
  extraScrollHeight={100}
  contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
   <Layout>
     <Content />
     <TextArea />
     <SubmitButton />
     <Comments />
   </Layout>
</KeyboardAvoidingScrollView>
```

Is it possible to disable this autoscoll behaviour? Or maybe there's a better way to implement this?

Relevant issue:
https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/333

Answer (score 1):

Android has two modes for the keyboard.  Mode one is pan.  It scrolls the screen such that the cursor is always on screen. In this mode, the keyboard opens on top of your app.  The other is resize.  In this mode, your app is resized above the keyboard and things are laid out again.  This can keep a button at the bottom of your screen, *if* your app is designed in a very Android specific way

You need resize.  That said, I don't know if resize will work well with react native, or think its possible to lay it out correctly in that tech stack.  You pretty much have to be doing an Android style layout to make that work.